# proving irrationality of cube-root of 2 using an specific method?

Tags: alternative-proof, irrational-numbers

One of the methods mentioned in *A Course of Pure Mathematics* for proving irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ is the following:

> Suppose, if possible, that $\frac{p}{q}$ is a positive fraction, in its lowest terms,
>   such that $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{2} = 2$ or $p^{2} = 2q^{2}$. It is easy to see that this involves
>   $(2q - p)^{2} = 2(p - q)^{2}$; and so $\frac{2q - p}{p - q}$ is another fraction having the
>   same property. But clearly $q < p < 2q$, and so $p - q < q$. Hence there is
>   another fraction equal to $\frac{p}{q}$ and having a smaller denominator, which
>   contradicts the assumption that $\frac{p}{q}$ is in its lowest terms.

This Method is similar to [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proof_by_infinite_descent.2C_not_involving_factoring) mentioned in Wikipedia, named "Proof by infinite descent, not involving factoring".

My question is,can this method be used for proving irrationality of $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}
$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, something similar can be made to work with an extra step. Suppose $\frac pq$ is $\sqrt[3]2$ in lowest terms. Then $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$ must be $\sqrt[3]4$ in lowest terms. Now we can check that $x=\frac{2q^2-p^2}{pq-q^2}$ also satisfies $x^3=4$. This has a smaller (but still positive) denominator than $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$, contradiction.

[edit to answer lhf's question] Set $y=\sqrt[3]2$, so that $2=y^3$. Then $2-y^2=y^3-y^2=y^2(y-1)$, and so $\Big(\frac{2-y^2}{y-1}\Big)^3=y^6=4$. Setting $y=p/q$ and multiplying top and bottom by $q^2$ gives the expresion for $x$ above. I think this generalises to $\sqrt[n]2$ by converting all cubes to $n$th powers and squares to $(n-1)$th powers, so you get a contradiction to $2^{(n-1)/n}$ being in lowest terms.

Comment: It'd be nice if you explained how you found $x$ and how this could be generalized to say $\sqrt[n]{2}$.

Comment: Sure; I've edited the answer to include that as it is a bit long for a comment.

Comment: thanks you for also covering the generalized part. what I like about this proof is the fact that it follows from $p < 2q$.